# Nested RecyclerViews with focusable elements java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

I have some nested recyclerviews which I need to scroll in sync, both on X and Y axis. The functionality is there, but when I made the elements focusable as this application is going be used in android TV environment I started getting the following error (crash):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6072)
```

This is happening when I am scrolling (using the keyboard arrow keys) to the very right side quickly (pressing the key and lifting it until I am at the end) and then doing the same thing to go at the bottom.

To see this in more detail here is a link of a github repository with the code and a youtube video displaying my behavior on the crash.
https://github.com/Dreyar/AndroidSynchronisedScrolling